# What is the expected value and variance of the given models?

Tags: statistics, time-series

I want to find the expected value and variance of these models but I am not quite sure what I need to do. The error term (white noise) is standard normally distributed. On the first one I am completely lost but would the expected value of the second and third be 0, since the expected value of error term sum to 0, and variance just sigma squared because we only have the error terms in the model? Help with how to find both for the first one will be appreciated.

$$Y_t=Y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$$
$$Y_t=\epsilon_t-\epsilon_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t-2}$$
$$Y_t=-\sum_{j=1}^t\epsilon_j$$

Comment: The variance of the sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances. If each $\epsilon_t$ has variance $1$, then in the second model the variance will be $1+1+1=3$.

Comment: The expectation of the first one stays constant as you keep adding expectations of $0$  so $\mathbb E(Y_t)=\mathbb E(Y_0)$.  If the error terms are all independent of everything then you can use @angryavian's comment to find the variance to find the variance of the first and third in the same way